# Affine scheme which is connected but not irreducible and not reduced.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Are there any examples of affine schemes which is connected but not irreducible and not reduced?. Reducedness and irredubility doesn't deduces connectedness, so I think there should be examples, but I cannot give specific examples...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a ring which has no nontrivial idempotents, has more than one minimal prime ideal and has some nilpotents.

First, connected but not irreducible: we can take $\mathbb Z[X]/(2X)$. It has no nontrivial idempotents, and it has the minimal prime ideals $(2)$ and $(X)$.

To make it not-reduced, we can change it to for example $\mathbb Z[X]/(4X)$, or $\mathbb Z[X,Y]/(2X,Y^2)$.